# How to make html page text and table responsive (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am trying to make a responsive webpage. I tried with `height`,`style.height`, `style.OffsetHeight`, etc. but I am not able to make a square table dynamically.

The below code changes the height but the table height and width do not match.

```
var width = table.offsetWidth;
table.setAttribute("style","height:"+ width + "px;");
```

- Should I apply the logic on cells or on table?
- How do I make the text(font-size) and other elements responsive?
- How to find 60% of screen height so that I calculate the minimum of width and height to set them as table parameters?

Design Pattern : [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj9pJ.png)

Code : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hvuv43m/4/)

Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have to use tables and js? If not then you get way easier responsive with divs and css. If we use css grid we don't necessarily even need media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can apply the logic on table. The below code will work for dynamic resizing:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',handlersize);

function handlersize(){
  width = table.offsetWidth;
  table.setAttribute("style", "height:" + width + "px;")
}
```

2. To change the font size, use css style font-size:3vw; or so depending upon requirement.

3.To get the 60% of screen height:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
height = element.offsetHeight;
height = height * 0.6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/1hvuv43m/3/)

You need to add `resize` **event listener** on window.
When window is resized, the function , `handlersize` will be called.
This will updated your tables height, everytime your window resizes

```
window.addEventListener('resize',handlersize);

function handlersize(){
  width = table.offsetWidth;
  table.setAttribute("style", "height:" + width + "px;")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It has partially solved my problem. Really appreciate your help. But, the table and the contents do not fit on the screen responsively according to the screen height and width.

Comment: Will u be using this app of urs on pc or mobile?

Comment: Mobile device !!

Answer (score 0):

I might be thinking that you need to implement a separate div based HTML structure for the mobile views.
As tables can't be that much responsive and you can display div based HTML structure using media queries.

Here's the Example of it.
https://codepen.io/amwill04/pen/QNPpqx

Code example:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="table" id="results">
  <div class='theader'>
    <div class='table_header'>Header One</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Two</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Three</div>
    <div class='table_header'>Header Four</div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.2726</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.1311</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.4782</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.9919</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.89</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.7986</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.876</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.498</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.1669</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.4949</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.7113</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.434</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>0.1996</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.7693</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>1.974</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.959</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='table_row'>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header One</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-1.5998</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Two</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.1149</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Three</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>1.3888</div>
    </div>
    <div class='table_small'>
      <div class='table_cell'>Header Four</div>
      <div class='table_cell'>-0.0689</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.table {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 10% auto 0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .table_row {
    display: table-row;
  }

  .theader {
    display: table-row;
  }

  .table_header {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
    border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
    background: #bdbdbd;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .table_header:first-child {
    border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  }

  .table_header:last-child {
    border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  }

  .table_small {
    display: table-cell;
  }

  .table_row > .table_small > .table_cell:nth-child(odd) {
    display: none;
    background: #bdbdbd;
    color: #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .table_row > .table_small > .table_cell {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    color: #5b5b5b;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  }

  .table_row > .table_small:first-child > .table_cell {
    border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
  }

  .table_row > .table_small:last-child > .table_cell {
    border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
  }

  .table_row:last-child > .table_small:last-child > .table_cell:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  }

  .table_row:last-child > .table_small:first-child > .table_cell:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  }

  .table_row:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background: #e9e9e9;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .table {
      width: 90%
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .table {
      display: block;
    }
    .table_row:nth-child(2n+3) {
      background: none;
    }
    .theader {
      display: none;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small > .table_cell:nth-child(odd) {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .table_cell {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .table_row {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: separate;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      margin: 5% auto 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .table_small {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:first-child > .table_cell:last-child {
      border-left: none;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small > .table_cell:first-child {
      border-left: #ccc 1px solid;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:first-child > .table_cell:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:first-child > .table_cell:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      border-top: #ccc 1px solid;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:last-child > .table_cell:first-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small > .table_cell:last-child {
      border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:last-child > .table_cell:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }
    .table_row > .table_small:last-child > .table_cell:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
```

Hope you got the point.

Comment: Thanks. Removed the table part in the code for text and timer. Will try to implement media queries as well.

Comment: I need the table dynamic via javascript.

Comment: I guess this answer is not related to the ask.